# webpack modules.export not defined

Tags: intellij-idea, webpack

NPM, Node and webpack versions are

```
C:\>npm --version
5.3.0

C:\>node --version
v6.10.2

C:\>webpack --version
3.3.0
```

I have created standard scala/Play2 project. In it, I added 4 Typescript files (Angular) in app/ts folder. I have also created the following webpack config file

```
modules.export = {
    entry: [
        '/ts/main.ts',
        '/ts/vendor.ts'
    ],
    output:{
        filename:'[name].bundle.js'
    },
    rules:
        {
            test:'/\.ts$/',
            loader:'awesome-typescript-loader'
        }
}
```

To make things run (download the dependencies and execute webpack to convert ts to js), I edited play configuration and added two npm commands in 'before launch' section (see pic). But on running the application, npm start declares error that module is not defined (refering to modules.export statement in webpack.config.js)

`[image]

At IntelliJ console

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" run start --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

> angular2-webpack@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\scala\play_programs\temp\app
> webpack

C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\scala\play_programs\temp\app\webpack.config.js:3
modules.export = {
^

ReferenceError: modules is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\scala\play_programs\temp\app\webpack.config.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\scala\play_programs\temp\app\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:96:18)
    at C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\scala\play_programs\temp\app\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:109:17

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start" "--scripts-prepend-node-path=auto"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-webpack@1.0.0 start: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack@1.0.0 start script 'webpack'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\scala\play_programs\temp\app\npm-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: FYI nodejs is now stable at version 8, and npm at version 5 which bring big performance improvements: [consider upgrading](https://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `webpack.config.js` must start with [`module.exports`](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) not `modules.export`.

It signifies programmatically the plain English equivalent: "this module exports".

Comment: thanks. I'll accept the answer shortly (have to wait 10 mins). Now I face a new issue - `throw new Error("'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename");` But I have defined output in webpack.config.js already.

Comment: Glad to hear it. That is indeed another problem. Perhaps because it doesn't specify a path? Try adding `path: __dirname + "/dist",` to the `output {}` object (or wherever you want your assets, relative to `__dirname` which is the folder `webpack.config.js` resides).

Comment: opened another bug - could you please reply there.  I added path but it still doesn't work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191495/webpack-doesnt-recognise-output-file-name