# webpack doesn't recognise output file name

Tags: webpack

Following is my webpack.config.js. I have specified an output file name but I still get error `throw new Error("'output.filename' is required, either in config file or as --output-filename")`

Does /public director need to exist or will webpack create one?

```
module.export = {
    entry: [
        '/ts/main.ts',
        '/ts/vendor.ts'
    ],
    output:{
        path: __dirname+'/public',
        filename:'[name].bundle.js'
    },
    rules:
        {
            test:'/\.ts$/',
            loader:'awesome-typescript-loader'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`module.exports` with an `s` at the end.

Your `module` is loading, but webpack doesn't find anything (i.e., your configuration) *exported*, so doesn't load `output` and never sees `filename` as a result.

Here's some more detail [on the nodejs module loader](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).